# check whether steps in a counter variable are missing

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a datafile with one row per participants (named 1-x, based on the study they took part in). I want to check whether all participants are present in the dataset. This is my toy dataset, personid are the participants, study is the study they took part in.

```
df <- read.table(text = "personid study measurement
1         x     23
2         x     32
1         y     21
3         y     23
4         y     23
6         y     23", header=TRUE)
```

which looks like this:

```
  personid study measurement
1        1    x          23
2        2    x          32
3        1    y          21
4        3    y          23
5        4    y          23
6        6    y          23
```

so for y, I am missing participants 2 and 5. How do I check that automatically? I tried adding a counter variable and comparing that counter variable to the participant id but once one participant is missing, the comparison is meaningless because the alignment is off.

```
df %>% group_by(study) %>% mutate(id = 1:n(),check = id==personid)
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: date [2]

  personid   study measurement    id check
     <int> <fctr>       <int> <int> <lgl>
1        1      x          23     1  TRUE
2        2      x          32     2  TRUE
3        1      y          21     1  TRUE
4        3      y          23     2 FALSE
5        4      y          23     3 FALSE
6        6      y          23     4 FALSE
```

Comment: What is the desired output you want here? Are you just trying to add this "check" column such that each row in the database is true if that participant is in every study?

Comment: Maybe the "check" column idea is not ideal, my desired output is something along the lines of "y is missing participants 2 and 5", don't care much about the format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `personid` is sequential, then you can do this using `setdiff`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(study) %>% 
 mutate(new = toString(setdiff(max(personid):min(personid), personid)))

#Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
#Groups: study [2]

#  personid  study measurement   new
#     <int> <fctr>       <int> <chr>
#1        1      x          23      
#2        2      x          32      
#3        1      y          21  5, 2
#4        3      y          23  5, 2
#5        4      y          23  5, 2
#6        6      y          23  5, 2
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use `tidy::expand()` to generate all possible combinations of `study` and `personid` and then use `anti_join()` to remove the combinations that actually appear in the data.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  expand(study, personid) %>% 
  anti_join(df)
#> Joining, by = c("study", "personid")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    study personid
#>   <fctr>    <int>
#> 1      y        2
#> 2      x        6
#> 3      x        4
#> 4      x        3
```

Comment: that is such a great idea, this would actually be the most useful output. although the example doesn't quite give the right output, I'd like to tell the script that for x I expect all numbers up to 2 (1:2) and for y all numbers up to 6 (1:6)

Comment: In that case, use expand() to generate the full set of possible values

Comment: that makes sense, but I can't wrap my head around how to have different max values to which I'm expanding. Do I just do 'expand(c("x","y"), 1:6)' and then exclude the rows I don't need (ie y 3-6)? Seems like there may be a more logical way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using base R

```
tapply(df$personid, df$study, function(a) setdiff(min(a):max(a), a))
```

Output:

```
$x
integer(0)

$y
[1] 2 5
```